# How to use Index and Match formulas for multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet that contains Olympic information, with the following fields in columns:

> A) Athlete, B) Age, C) Country, D) Year, E) Closing Ceremony Date, F) Sport G) Gold Medals.

I want to answer this question about the data:

*What is the name of an athlete who won the most gold medals for the following country, for any year?*

The country is Norway (in `D38`). Any help?

I was initially using the formula:

```
 =INDEX(OlympicAthletes!A:A,MATCH(MAX(OlympicAthletes!G:G),OlympicAthletes!G:G,0),1)
```

However, this only returns Michael Phelps. I need the formula to return the athlete with the highest gold medals for Norway. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a repetitive array formula. It's not that pretty, but it will get you what you want. Type in the following and enter by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=INDEX(A:A,MAX(IF(C:C="Norway",IF(G:G=MAX(IF(C:C="Norway",G:G,-1)),ROW(G:G),-1),-1)))
```

What this does (besides make you appreciate SQL):

- `IF(C:C="Norway",G:G,-1)` represents an array the length of column C that contains the value from column G if the country for that record is Norway and `-1` if the country is not Norway.
- `MAX(IF(C:C="Norway",G:G,-1))` returns the max value from this array, which should be the max number of medals won by a Norwegian in your table.
- `IF(C:C="Norway",IF(G:G=MAX(IF(C:C="Norway",G:G,-1)),ROW(G:G),-1),-1)` checks all the rows for two conditions: first, that the athlete is Norwegian, and second, that the number of gold medals won by that athlete is equal to the maximum number won by a Norwegian. The result of this expression is an array the length of column C that contains the row number if both conditions are met or `-1` if they are not.
- `MAX(IF(C:C="Norway",IF(G:G=MAX(IF(C:C="Norway",G:G,-1)),ROW(G:G),-1),-1))` returns the maximum value from this array. This will be the row number of the match. If there happens to be more than one row that meets the criteria, this will return the one with the largest row number.
- Finally, `INDEX(A:A,MAX(IF(C:C="Norway",IF(G:G=MAX(IF(C:C="Norway",G:G,-1)),ROW(G:G),-1),-1)))` returns the value (name) from column A in the row number identified as meeting the criteria.

A quick word of warning:

Beware that using full column references, e.g., `A:A`, in an array formula will have a noticeable negative impact on calculation speed. If at all possible, you should use limited ranges, like `A1:A10` instead, especially if you're creating several of these formulas in your workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about putting your data into a PivotTable. It allows you to summarise and query your data in multiple ways. Specifically, if you created a PivotTable with row headers Year, then Country, then Athlete, then add the Gold Medals to the data area. This will break the data up for you very precisely and give you access to filters you can use to query it more easily.